# update a table based on the outcome of a join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I understand the syntax here:

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE conditions;
```

and here:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT expression1
               FROM table2
               WHERE conditions)
WHERE conditions;
```

...but what if I want to update

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = expression
if we get a particular result on a join between table1 and table2
which has WHERE conditions?
```

I can't seem to figure it out, and I get syntax errors in all of my attempts. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE table1 JOIN
       table2
       ON conditions
    SET table1.column1 = table2.expression1
    WHERE conditions;
```

Comment: Stepping back and looking at it, it's confusing syntax, since it starts with `UPDATE` yet the real updating is done much further down in the `SET` statement. It's as if the keyword `UPDATE` really doesn't need to be there. I feel like you could change the keyword `UPDATE` to `FOO` and there would be no loss of information.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck . . . The `update` specifies the table being operated on.  The `set` specifies the columns.  This is actually the same distinction used for `select` and `from`.  `Update` is more reasonable (in my opinion) because it defines the data sources first.

Comment: so basically you are saying `UPDATE` is short for `UPDATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is write it as a SELECT statement first.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.col   AS old_val
     , s.expr  AS new_val
  FROM target_table t
  JOIN source_table s
    ON s.somecol = t.somecol
   AND s.othercol < 1
 WHERE s.something_else = 'abc'
```

In this example, `t.col` is the column that I (eventually) want to assign a new  value to. (Used in the SELECT statement here, this just displays the value currently stored in the column.)

The expression `s.expr` represents the expression that returns the value I want to assign to `col`.  This could be as simple as a column reference, or can be a more complex expression.

The rest of the statement are the normal `FROM`, `JOIN`, `ON` and `WHERE` clauses we're familiar with.

Once I have a `SELECT` statement that is working, I can convert that into an UPDATE statement by

- replacing **`SELECT ... FROM`** (at the beginning of the statement) with the keyword **`UPDATE`**
- adding a **`SET`** clause before the **`WHERE`** clause.

For example, I would convert the SELECT statement above to something like this, to assign the value of `s.expr` to `t.col`:

```
UPDATE target_table t
  JOIN source_table s
    ON s.somecol = t.somecol
   AND s.othercol < 1
   SET t.col = s.expr
 WHERE s.something_else = 'abc'
```

This the approach that works for me. Writing it as a SELECT first allows me to test, muck with the conditions and expressions, and review to verify which rows are going to be updated, what values are being replaced, and what values are going to be assigned to each row.